# How to save the value of a form in custom object of salesforce

Tags: apex

my apexpage and controller is

```
<apex:page Controller="test_validation">
  <apex:form >
      <apex:pageBlock >
          <apex:pageblockButtons>
              <apex:commandButton action="{!Save}" value="Save"/>
          </apex:pageblockButtons>

          <apex:pageBlockSection>
              <apex:inputField label="Summary" value="{!testvalidation.Sumary__c}"/>
              <apex:inputField value="{!testvalidation.Class__c}" label="Class"/>
          </apex:pageBlockSection>  
                </apex:pageBlock>
  </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

---

```
public class test_validation {
    public test_validation__c testvalidation{get;set;}
    public test_validation__c vartest{get;set;}

    public PageReference Save(){
        vartest=new test_validation__c();
        vartest.Sumary__c=??????
        vartest.Class__c=??????
        insert vartest;
        return null;
    }
}
```

i want to know how to access vf input field in apex class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You save the same instance that the Visualforce page is bound to. When the form is submitted the platform updates the fields and then you can save the instance:

```
public class test_validation {
    public test_validation__c testvalidation{get;set;}
    public test_validation() {
        testvalidation = new test_validation__c();
    }
    public PageReference Save(){
        insert testvalidation;
        return null;
    }
}
```

This [Visualforce Workbook](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/workbook_vf/workbook_vf.pdf) explains this and many other important concepts.