# Why is my save function giving me an error (REQUIRED_FIELD_MISING)?

Tags: apex, visualforce

I built my save function off of the answer from: [How to save the value of a form in custom object of salesforce](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/54554/how-to-save-the-value-of-a-form-in-custom-object-of-salesforce). The page works fine until I click on the save button, which then throws me an error.

Below is my code:

```
public with sharing class MyExtension
{
    public String ServiceCaseID {get;set;}
    public List<Part__c> parts { get; private set; }
    public Service_Case__c[] SC { get; private set; }
    public PartsInProduct__c[] partsInProducts {get; private set;}
    public String productName {get;set;}
    public PartsinProduct__c  myObj {get; set;}


    public MyExtension(ApexPages.StandardController controller)
    {
        ServiceCaseID  = ApexPages.CurrentPage().getparameters().get('id');
        SC = [select id,LGFProduct__r.name  from Service_case__c where id =: ServiceCaseID];

        productname = SC[0].LGFProduct__r.name;
        partsInProducts = [SELECT name, id, 
               (SELECT Part__r.name, Part__r.id, Quantity_Needed__c 
                 FROM PartsinProducts__r 
                 )
            FROM LGFProduct__c where name = :Productname ][0].PartsinProducts__r;

        //before we can use the object on the page we need to create an instance of it.
        myObj = new PartsinProduct__c(); 
    }


    public PageReference Save()
    {
        insert myObj;
        return null;
    }


}
```

VF Page

```
<!--<apex:page standardController="Service_Case__c" extensions="MyExtension">
    <apex:pageBlock >
        <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!parts}" var="part">
            <apex:column value="{!part.name}"/> 
            <apex:column value="{!part.id}"/> 
        </apex:pageBlockTable>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:page>-->

<apex:page standardController="Service_Case__c" extensions="MyExtension">
    <apex:form >
    <apex:pageBlock >
        <apex:pageBlockButtons location="top" >
            <apex:commandButton action="{!Save}" value="Save" id="theButton"/> 
        </apex:pageBlockButtons>
        <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!partsInProducts}" var="pip">
            <apex:column value="{!pip.Part__r.Name}"/> 
            <apex:column value="{!pip.Part__r.id}"/>
            <!--<apex:inputField value="{!pip.Quantity_Needed__c}"/>-->
            <apex:column headerValue="Order Quantity" style="text-align:center">
                    <apex:inputField value="{!pip.Quantity_Needed__c}" style="text-align:center"/>
            </apex:column>
        </apex:pageBlockTable>
    </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Pictures of before and after

[image]

after clicking save

[image]

Comment: That's the most descriptive status code you could ever wish for. `REQUIRED_FIELD_MISING`. Then the message tells you what they are. `Required Fields are missing: [LGFProduct, Part]: [LGFProduct, Part]`. Seems obvious, no?

Comment: So in my column I have to have all the required fields of LGFProduct and Part? I tried to make it so that the form would only take an number for input and the use would see which part, I didn't want to show anything else, but if its required, i guess I have to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have `LGFProduct` field as required in your `PartsinProduct__c` sObject. Unles you set a non null value for that field in your code (as input or directly in the code):

```
myObj.requiredField__c = <non null value>
```

you'll receive that error in your insert operation.

If it's not intended to be required, just disable the option:

Setup->Create->Objects->PartsinProduct__c

Under **Custom Fields & Relationships** edit the field and uncheck the option:

[image]

Comment: I can't make it not required because it is in a master detail relationship. For the requiredField__c equals null value above, I put it in Apex right because even when I append a ; to the end of that phrase, myObj.requiredField__c = <non null value>; , I am given the error: unexpected token: '<'.

Comment: The point isn't to make the field not required, it's to populate it. You're supposed to replace `<non null value>` with an actual value. In this case, it should be the Id of a master record.

Comment: I just realized it myself reading it, sigh I'm not thinking :/

Comment: @user1470901 Sometimes it happens :)